# How to enable hints and warnings in the online REPL

Tags: frege

I figured that I can do it on the command line REPL like so:

```
java -jar frege-repl-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar -hints -warnings
```

But how can I do the same in http://try.frege-lang.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints and warnings are already enabled by default. For example,

```
frege> f x = f x
function f :: α -> β
3: application of f will diverge.
```

Perhaps we can make it better by explicitly saying it as warning or hint (instead of colors distinguishing them) something like:

```
[Warning] 3: application of f will diverge.
```

and providing an option to turn them on/off.

**Update:**
There was indeed an issue (Thanks Ingo for pointing that out!) with showing warnings that are generated in a later phase during the compilation. [This issue](https://github.com/Frege/try-frege/issues/13) has been fixed and the following examples now correctly display warnings in the REPL:

```
frege> h x = 0; h false = 42
function h :: Bool -> Int
4: equation or case alternative cannot be reached.

frege> f false = 6
function f :: Bool -> Int
5: function pattern is refutable, consider
adding a case for true
```

Comment: I see, but how comes that some warnings do not appear. Like `g true = 43` now there should be a warning about the missing equation for `g false ...`

Comment: Another one: `h x = 0; h false = 42` should warn that the second equation is never used.

Comment: I am not sure why those warnings are not getting displayed. I will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Note that some warnings and hints, like the above ones, are emitted in the code generation pass. Maybe you fetch the warnings too early?

Comment: Thanks! yes, that is exactly the problem. In REPL, for definitions, code generation phase is skipped since we are not going to evaluate anything. For modules and expressions, code generation is always enabled. To fix this issue, I think we should always enable codegen.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know this. Very clever, indeed. But when I use the function, you have to compile it anyway, haven't you?

Comment: yes, compilation always happens. It is just code generation that will not be enabled for definitions until you type an expression later. At that time all the definitions you have entered and successfully compiled will be included along with the expression you just typed in.

Comment: @Ingo I have fixed this issue by enabling code generation always.

Comment: Great! Thank you for doing this.